# HTML record voice button

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there any code for a button to record voice from mic using html or java script and save it in mysql database. Actually m planning for voice commenting.

Comment: People here are curious to know, what research have you done ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is an example on the Microsoft Edge website. It shows recording voice, it's then possible to get the data which could be saved somewhere. Not sure a mySql database would be a good candidate but you could probably dump it in there a a blob

https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/testdrive/demos/microphone/